# how can i change complete package name of an android app?

Tags: android, smali, apk-expansion-files

I have decompiled an voip calling apk file with Apktool and I tried to change its package name but I am getting an error that `unfortunately app stopped`...

What I did that search the package name inside all the files `(root dir)`and `replace every occurrence` with new package name by with `notepad ++`.

Here is the problem that app use to `communicate their server` same as package name so it would cause an error `"unfortunately stoped!!!` "

How can I `replace only that package name` without effecting other name that have the same package name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right click on your project, navigate to `Android Tools` and select `Rename Application package`.

Comment: Use development IDE (Android Studio or Eclipse) instead of notepad ++ for renaming package.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i modify package name of decompiled apk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272244/how-can-i-modify-package-name-of-decompiled-apk)

Answer (score 0):

> You don't n required to manually replace the package name in every
>   source file

Right click on the `package name ---> Rename --> Type your new package name & choose Refactor`

(This option will automatically `replace all references associated` with the package name including in `manifest file`. )

Answer (score 0):

you should try to import the project into Eclipse or any other IDE.
then change the Package name only. Thank You.
Hope this will Solve your Problem