# how can i modify package name of decompiled apk?

Tags: java, android, package, apk, decompiler

I have decompiled a voip calling apk file with Apktool and i tried to change itz package name... But i getting error that unfortunately app stopped`...

What i did that search the package name inside the all files (root dir)and replace every occurrence with new package name by with notepad ++...

Here problem is that app using to communicate their server by with same as package name so it would cause error " unfortunately stoped!!! "

How can i replace only that package name without effecting other name that have same package name
Any app available. for package renaming? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I mean: if the app is yours; there is nothing that prevents you from changing your own source code. If the app is not yours - then doing what you suggest could be a violation of 3rd party rights.

Comment: _communicate their server_ - Why do you want it to communicate with their server and not your server?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as stackoverflow does not encourage software piracy.

Comment: Beware... you will soon have **legal troubles**.

Answer (score 3):

The package name of an app has nothing to do with any class names, it's just an entry in the manifest. It's usually the same as the name of one of the packages in the application but it doesn't have to be. Don't do a global search and replace (which may mess things up), just edit the package name in the manifest. Note that activity, receiver, and service names are often specified in the manifest relative to the app package name. If this is the case (they start with a dot), you'll have to change them to absolute class names as well.

If an application gets a "suddenly stopped" error, look at the Logcat output to see what the error was. There's countless reasons an application can crash so it's impossible to guess based on the description you gave.